# How to handle parameters in activity if user select my application from sharing list?

Tags: android, list, sharing

I am now able to display my android application in default sharing list of applications when user click on email address from gmail account on android mobile.

But how can i get the email address in my applications to field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Sharing Content training](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html), in particular [Handle the Incoming Content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content).

```
String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);
```